# How to completely remove the top section with the menu?

Tags: menus

I am using a child of Pixova Lite 2.0.4 on Wordpress 5.1.1 running on local machine to make a landing page. I want my header image to start from the very top of the page with no top menu section over it. How do I get rid of the top section with the menu?[image]

Answer (score -1):

If there is no option to disable that sticky header, u can use css.. inspect its div, then hide it with display : none;

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It worked. It might have been s simple answer for you,  but for a novice like me it meant the world!!!